# Wrong validation message is displaying by knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am using knokcout.js and knockout.validation plugin. I have an issue in my code with validation messages. I applied 2 validation on observable field (say password) like :

**In Js Code**

```
..
this.Password = ko.observable().extend({
       required: { message: "Enter password" },
       minLength: { params: 6, message: "Must be 6 chars long" }
});
..
```

**In Html**

```
<input type="password" data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate:'afterkeypress"
  placeholder="Password" />
```

Now my problem is when i enter single character in the password filed than instead of showing validation message `(Must be 6 chars long)` it shows me message `(Enter password)` and than when i enter second character in the field than it shows me message `(Must be 6 chars long)`. And this behavior is with all fields on which i applied validation. Can anybody please tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: Check it by replacing afterkeypress event with onBlur event.

Comment: i check this already with keypress , keyup and onBlur, but not working

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be reacting to the 'keypress' rather than 'afterkeypress'. You are missing a single quote after 'afterkeypress' in your sample html.

The documentation doesn't really list 'afterkeypress' as an updateValue option, but it does seem work in my tests.

[From documentation for value binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)

> If your binding also includes a parameter called valueUpdate, this
>   defines additional browser events KO should use to detect changes
>   besides the change event. The following string values are the most
>   commonly useful choices:
>
> - "keyup" - updates your view model when the user releases a key
> - "keypress" - updates your view model when the user has typed a key. Unlike keyup, this updates repeatedly while the user holds a key down
> - "afterkeydown" - updates your view model as soon as the user begins typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s keydown event
>     and handling the event asynchronously.
>
> Of these options, "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to
>   keep your view model updated in real-time.

The documenation recommends using the 'afterkeydown' choice for best results, and I found that to be the case.

I created a sample which uses 'keypress', 'afterkeypress' and 'afterkeydown'.

See: http://jsbin.com/anerop/3/edit  (validatedObservable; Note: Click the "Run with js" button)

Binding to 'afterkeydown' seems to provide the best user experience.  The 'afterkeypress' doesn't update until the control loses focus.

Sample data-bind:

```
<input type="password" data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"
  placeholder="Password" />
```

I created another example which did not use validatedObservable and got similar results.

See: http://jsbin.com/itatic/1/edit  (not validatedObservable; Note: Click the "Run with js" button)